# How to find all possible sums of all digits of integer?

Tags: c#, algorithm, sum-of-digits

I need to find all possible sums of all digits of integer.
Input: 234

Output: 36

Explanation: (**2**+3+**2**+4)+(**3**+2+**3**+4)+(**4**+2+**4**+3)

But I only know how to find the sum of the firs and last digit:

```
int num, sum = 0, firstDigit, lastDigit;

Console.Write("Enter any number: ");

num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

lastDigit = num % 10;

firstDigit = num;

while (num >= 10)
{
num = num / 10;
}
firstDigit = num;


sum = firstDigit + lastDigit;

Console.WriteLine("Sum of first and last digit: " + sum);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: For the two digit sum you'd just do `i % 100` and for the 3 digit `i % 1000`

Comment: What do you mean summing all the digits? is it all the the substrings from the original number? Is it for instance include: `13` for the number: `123`? What are you trying to achieve??

Comment: FYI 1+2+3+12+23+123 = 164 not 177 unless like @JackRaBeat said you want to include 13 in the sum

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mentioned 13